# SQL request, inner joins on same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a SQL table tbl_client_condition like this:

```
id_client | id_condition
1         | A
1         | B
1         | C
2         | A
2         | B
3         | A
3         | B
3         | C
3         | D
4         | C
5         | C
5         | D
```

I want to get all the clients that have A, B and C conditions. So in that example I want client 1 and 3.

I am not too sure how to do this, especially the number of conditions I want is not defined. This works for 2 conditions A and B for instance:

```
SELECT a.id_client
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM tbl_client_condition
WHERE id_condition = A
) AS a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM tbl_client_condition
WHERE id_condition = B
) AS b ON a.id_client = b.id_client
```

But if I want records for 10 id_conditions I don't want to do 10 INNER JOIN...

I am sure there must be an easy solution.

Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using? mysql, oracel, mssql?

Comment: I am using MySQL, bvr answer works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT [id_client] FROM table1
WHERE [id_condition] IN ('A','B','C')
GROUP BY [id_client]
HAVING COUNT(distinct [id_condition]) = 3
```

**<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0426d/1)</kbd>**

Here `COUNT(distinct [id_condition]) = 3` changes with number of values used in `IN` condition